# Is it possible to make my players really care about NPCs?

Tags: gm-techniques, npc

What I'd really like to do, and don't think I have right tools/approach, is to emotionally manipulate my players into making sub-optimal  - even bad - decisions using the NPCs I present them with.

"I can't believe John did that to Jill, let's get him!"
"Little Billy is going to die unless we do X"
"I know she *said* she'd destroyed that town but c'mon, it's Claire, she's our friend..."

Making NPCs stand out and memorable isn't the point here, I want the players to really care about them.

Can this be done?

I've read the brilliant answers [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51510/how-to-create-meaningful-relationships-with-npcs/51707#51707) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/how-do-i-help-my-players-get-more-engaged-in-the-story/41085#41085) but want to know if there are any near-guaranteed methods for achieving this, specific examples and the like.

Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is to follow the advice in questions you've already quoted. There are no near-guaranteed methods in RPGs at all, it depends on how well you know the group and the group itself - and no one can judge that but yourself. So yes, it can be done, but there is no simple answer. BTW, I think this is not a question that could get a good answer - but you're welcome to [RPG.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) to discuss more freely!

Comment: Fair enough, worth a shot I thought. Thanks for the insight.